# How can I automatically refresh filtered data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets of data; 'Master' contains information about cargo and it's location, 'X ray' contains all rows matching the same location.

I've created a true/false statement that checks location and pulls all relevant data to 'X ray'. That is working perfectly. However, i have to re apply the filter to see the changes.

I want the filter in 'x ray' to auto refresh when a change is made in the 'master' sheet.

The column i'm filtering is 'IF True' in A1, When the data displays 'True, show row.

I've tried many of the different methods on stack overflow, but with no success. I have low level ability with VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have the "auto refresh" only by using Pivot tables. Try to create your second tables as linked pivot table using the data from the first table.

Comment: With the data in the second sheet. I don't want it to be a report. But editable data, that links back to the first sheet